# Is $\nabla \cdot (\nabla\times \textbf{F})$ = div $\textbf{F} $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, rotations, stokes-theorem, divergence-theorem

Is $\nabla \cdot (\nabla\times \textbf{F})$ = div $\textbf{F} $?

Where $(\nabla\times \textbf{F})$ = rot $\textbf{F}$. If yes, why?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Not really, I am not searching for the interpretation if the expression equals zero, but if you can calculate the divergence using the curl.

Comment: There is no "**if**" the expression equals zero.  You have failed to read the answers to the cited question.

Comment: The question you have suggested is "was wondering if there were a similar $\textbf{explanation}$ for div curl =0."

Comment: And the various **answers** show that div curl F is always zero.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it would be true to begin with? Did you try it out on a few examples? You should be able to very easily convince yourself that the identity does *not* hold in general.

Comment: @HansLundmark My professor used that expression when solving a question using Gauss's theorem once we had the curl,

Comment: Oh, I see. I think the best person to ask in this case would be your professor, who knows what the context is. Maybe he or she actually meant to write something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. In fact, $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times F)=\sum_{ijk}\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_i\partial_j F_k=0$, because $\epsilon_{ijk}$ ($\partial_i\partial_j$) is antisymmetric (symmetric) under $i\leftrightarrow j$.